# Angular app (localhost) stuck on loading after ng-serve

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular, but I am having a problem loading the app on localhost. Im using Angular 7.

The ng serve code compiles, but nothing shows up on localhost and there are no console errors.

> Date: 2019-05-31T19:26:07.997Z
>
> Hash: bcc13e1171410099bc0d
>
> Time:16984ms
>
> chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 16 kB [initial]
>   [rendered] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map
>   (polyfills) 248 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {polyfills-es5}
>   polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 380 kB
>   [initial] [rendered] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map
>   (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered] chunk {styles} styles.js,
>   styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {vendor}
>   vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.01 MB [initial] [rendered]
>
> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ ** i ｢wdm｣: Compiled
>   successfully.

[image of localhost and web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeR5k.png)

app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing-module.ts

```js
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

home.component.ts

```js
import { AuthService } from './../services/auth.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'oshop3';
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/cli">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: add the `app.component.ts` in the question

Comment: @renanzin done it

Comment: Are you sure you are on Angular 7? (polyfills-es5)

Comment: Are you running your app on IE or Edge? If so you should uncomment some imports from polyfils.ts. Try it on Chrome or Firefox plz.

Comment: @pindev according to the screenshot it looks like Firefox

Comment: That is weird, I do notice that you have some firefox plugins installed. Maybe try using incognito or a different browser?